# SDWebImage causes a "not a prototype" warning

Tags: xcode, sdwebimage

I'm working on an IOS app and I'm using SDWebImage (v 3.8.2 installed with Cocoa Pods). When I compile I get a warning that reads:

```
This block declaration is not a prototype
```

This error refers to the line

```
typedef void(^SDWebImageNoParamsBlock)();
```

in the SDWebImageCompat.h file.

Is there a way to fix this? I tried updating the pod but this seems to be the latest version.

I'm using XCode 9.0.

Answer (score 1):

`inhibit_all_warnings!` doesn't work for me. I add a pch file to the project, and add `#pragma` resolved warnings. Hope it can help you.

```
// Suppress warnings of framework
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wstrict-prototypes"

#import <TheWarningPods/File.h>
@import TheWarningPods;

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `inhibit_warnings => true` to your Podfile:

```
pod 'SDWebImage', :inhibit_warnings => true
```

Basically this will silence all warnings for the specified pod.

Alternatively, you can add `inhibit_all_warnings!` to the top of your Podfile to silence all warnings for all pods.